# JavaScript Proxy usage

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I'm learning ES6 and found a Proxy object. In total, I got how it actually works. But my question about Proxy usage. As example I attached shows, proxy is created from user object. To "listen" or "trap" events happening with proxy we should use a proxy object, but it's not what I want. Is there a way to "listen" events, which happen with original (user) object?

```
let user = {};

let proxy = new Proxy(user, {
    get(target, prop) {
        alert(`Reading ${prop}`);
        return target[prop];
    }, 
});

proxy.firstName;  // Reading firstName
```

To make things clear, lets imagine a situation: I've got some object, which works incorrectly. I want to figure out what goes wrong with it and create a proxy. So, next in my code I should use a proxy instead of my original wrong-working object? So, as I see a solution of this problem, it should work kinda this:

```
let user = {} // wrong-working object
let proxy = new Proxy(user, {
    get(target, prop) {
        alert(`Reading ${prop}`);
        return target[prop];
    }, 
}); // new Proxy returns proxy which is just used for removing "event-listener"
user.firstName // Reading firstName
```

Can I get any explanation, why it does work this way?

Comment: No, you cannot change an object into a proxy. A proxy always only serves as a wrapper around the target.

Comment: "*I've got some object, which works incorrectly. I want to figure out what goes wrong with it*" - use a debugger for that, not a proxy. You can often set data breakpoints in them.